# how to read a csv and write it back exactly the same with pandas overcoming float imprecision

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I would like to read in a csv and write it back exactly the same as it was using pandas or similar

example csv

```
019-12-12 23:45:00,95480,12.41,-10.19,11.31851,2.1882
```

and when I go to write it back, due to floating point properties i might get something like

```
019-12-12 23:45:00,95480,12.410000009,-10.19,11.31851.000000002,2.1822
```

I've seen suggestions to use `float_format` but the format is different for each column and different across files I'm looping through.

Comment: Are you making any changes to the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but if you need pandas and want to re-save the file, you likely will want to change data somewhere. If so, I'd recommend using

```
df.set_option('precision', num_decimals)
```

as long as your decimals are reasonably close in precision, in the example given, 4 would allow for enough precision and remove any straggling floating point inaccuracy. Otherwise, you'll have to look for several zeros in a row and delete all decimal places after that.

If you don't need to change any data, I would go with an alternative solution: [shutil](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shutil-copyfile-method/)

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(path_to_file, path_to_target_file)
```

This way, there's no mutation that can occur as it's just copying the raw contents.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try, I think that should work.  My issue is that sometimes I do need to add in additional data to the dataframe and a copy doesn't work for those occasions.  Basically the script is designed to run weekly and append/concatenate the data table in a cloud directory if changes have occurred in any of two parent files.  I'd like to keep the files as identical as possible in both locations.